# Limesurvey 3 Answers Slider Bar

Tags: slider, limesurvey

I have a slider bar where I have two answer choices along with the choices "No answer" and "I'm unsure" which were modified in Javascript. I wanted to add another answer choice, to have three in total.

Does anyone know how to do this using Limesurvey or Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing you want to do?

I used element type "Multiple numerical input" and changed settings to:
Use slider layout:  Yes
Slider minimum value:   0
Slider maximum value:   100
Slider accuracy:    1
Slider initial value:   0
Allow reset the slider: Yes

[image: Is this the kind of thing you want to do?]